# Calling a separate function from within a fork() child process

Tags: c, unix, pipe, fork

I have been working on this fork() project. I have it working as needed when coded all in main(), but I want to be able to have each child call it's function from a separate file rather than have it all in main(). I have them linked in a static library. I am getting no errors or warnings on compile but when I run i get interesting output.

The ultimate goal is to move on to named pipes with these three separate files. But I want to understand how this works.

Current main():

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX 180
#define PipeStdIn 0             //UNIX StdIn
#define PipeStdOut 1            //UNIX StdOut

void lifeSupport();
void navigation();

int main()
{
    const char *message = {"Calibrate Systems\n"};
    int pipes[2], ret;
    char buf[MAX + 1];



    if(pipe(pipes) == 0)
    {
        if(fork() == 0)
        {
            lifeSupport();
        }
        else
        {       
            ret = write(pipes[PipeStdOut], message, strlen(message) + 1);                   //write

            ret = wait(NULL);

            ret = read(pipes[PipeStdIn], buf, MAX);

            time_t now;
            time(&now);
            printf("Report received: %s\n", buf);
            printf("Report time: %s\n", ctime(&now));


            if(fork() == 0)
            {
                navigation();
            }
            else
            {       
                ret = write(pipes[PipeStdOut], message, strlen(message) + 1);                   //write

                ret = wait(NULL);

                ret = read(pipes[PipeStdIn], buf, MAX);

                time_t now;
                time(&now);
                printf("Report received: %s\n", buf);
                printf("Report time: %s\n", ctime(&now));
            }

        }
    }

    close(pipes[PipeStdIn]);
    close(pipes[PipeStdOut]);

    return 0;
}
```

Current lifeSupport function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX 180
#define PipeStdIn 0             //UNIX StdIn
#define PipeStdOut 1            //UNIX StdOut

void lifeSupport()
{

    int pipes[2], ret;
    char buf[MAX + 1];


    ret = read(pipes[PipeStdIn], buf, MAX);             //read

    printf("Life Support receives instruction: %s\n", buf);     //notification confirming life support has received the command from parent

    sleep(5);           //5 second sleep to simulate adjustment of breathing gas levels

    sleep(4);           //4 second sleep to simulate adjustment of lighting and temp levels                                         


    //message informing that the levels have completed adjusting
    const char *breathGL = {"Breathing gas levels have been adjusted\n\t\t Adjustment time: 5 seconds\n\t\t Lighting and temperture levels have been adjusted\n\t\t Adjustment time: 4 seconds"};

    ret = write(pipes[PipeStdOut], breathGL, strlen(breathGL) + 1);         //write
}
```

Current navigation function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX 200
#define PipeStdIn 0             //UNIX StdIn
#define PipeStdOut 1            //UNIX StdOut

void navigation()
{
    printf("test");
    int pipes[2], ret;
    char buf[MAX + 1];

    ret = read(pipes[PipeStdIn], buf, MAX);     //read

    //notification confirming navigation has received the command from parent
    printf("\nNavigation receives instruction: %s\n", buf);

    //generates a random number between 0 & 6 to use as simulated adjustment time
    sleep(rand() % 7);

    //message informing that the levels have completed adjusting
    const char *nav = {"Navigation system has been adjusted\n\t\t Adjustment time: 0-6 seconds"};

    ret = write(pipes[PipeStdOut], nav, strlen(nav) + 1);       //write
}
```

Expected output:

```
Life Support receives instruction: Calibrate Systems

Report received: Breathing gas levels have been adjusted
         Adjustment time: 5 seconds
         Lighting and temperture levels have been adjusted
         Adjustment time: 4 seconds
Report time: Tue Apr 28 09:50:47 2020


Navigation receives instruction: Calibrate Systems

Report received: Navigation system has been adjusted
         Adjustment time: 3 seconds
Report time: Tue Apr 28 09:50:50 2020
```

Current incorrect results:

```
Life Support receives instruction: ���
Report received: Calibrate Systems

Report time: Tue Apr 28 23:34:11 2020
```

At this point it freezes and I have to ctrl+c to stop it.

I am still very new to fork() so I assumed that I would be able to call a function like this. Apparently there is more to it than that and I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: Please post `lab4staticlib.h`.

Comment: In the `lifesupport()` function you have: `int pipes[2], ret;
    char buf[MAX + 1];


    ret = read(pipes[PipeStdIn], buf, MAX);` — you're using an uninitialized variable `pipes` so happiness is not one of your options.  You probably need to pass the opened pipe file descriptors to the function as arguments.  You save system call return values in `ret` which is good, but only if you also check that you didn't get an error.

Comment: @Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica I was mistaken. I was looking at an older version. I edited my post to reflect.

Comment: So I would need to do something along the lines of `int send_fd(int fd, int fd_to_send);`?

Comment: Generally, it behooves you to develop new functionality *in isolation* as much as possible. Most of the code you posted has nothing to do with the basic problem (i.e. pipe communication between a parent and a couple of children), and it's making the bug much harder to see.

Comment: I got myself in the habit of posting the entire code because in the past I haven't posted enough. That coupled with the fact that I am asking this question because I don't know exactly where the bug is coming from. I find it much more helpful to make the entire thing available from the get go.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring separate arrays called `pipes` in all three of your functions. Different variables with the same name don't magically get initialized with the same values. You need to pass them as parameters to the functions instead.